# How we Create Custom Decorator that can apply on file field and radio button selection

Tags: decorator

if We apply any custom decorator on radio button then it will be display on next line so how 
we create such custom decorator that will display inline also same for file

Answer (score 0):

checked=false;
function checkedAll (frm1) {
    var aa= document.getElementById('frm1');
     if (checked == false)
          {
           checked = true
          }
        else
          {
          checked = false
          }
    for (var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++) 
    {
     aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
    }
      }
function check()
    {
        var aa= document.getElementById('frm1');
        var flag;
        for(var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++)
        {
            if(aa.elements[i].type=='checkbox')
            {
                if(aa.elements[i].checked && aa.elements[i].id !='checkall')
                {
                    flag = true;

```
            }
            else if(!aa.elements[i].checked && aa.elements[i].id !='checkall')
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag)
    {
        aa.elements.checkall.checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        aa.elements.checkall.checked = false;
    }
}
function notempty()
```

{
    var flag=false;
    var all ='';
    var aa= document.getElementById('frm1');
    for(var i =0; i < aa.elements.length; i++)
    {
        if(aa.elements[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
            if(aa.elements.checkall.checked)
            {
                flag = true;
                all = 'd';
                break;
            }
            else
            {//alert(aa.elements[i].id);
                if(aa.elements[i].checked && aa.elements[i].id !='checkall')
                    {
                        flag = true;

```
                    all += aa.elements[i].id.replace('check','') + '~';
                }
        }
    }
}
if(!flag)
{
    alert("please select a contact to delete..");
    return false;
}
if(flag)
{

    //alert(all);
    document.location.href= '/member/public/index/delete?all='+all;
    return false;
}
```

}

onclick='checkedAll(frm1);'>

escape($data->id);?>"

onclick="check();">

10px;"  onclick="return notempty();" value="DELETE" />

Comment: <form id ="frm1">
<th scope="col"><input type='checkbox' id="checkall" name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll(frm1);'></th>

<td><input type="checkbox" id="check<?php echo $this->escape($data->id);?>" onclick="check();"></td>

<input type="button" style="float:right; margin-right: 20%; margin-top: 10px;"  onclick="return notempty();" value="DELETE" />